# Two CPU in two modes - VMX and non-VMX modes

Tags: virtual-machine, cpu, root, hardware, virtualization

In a dual or multi-CPU configuration, is it possible for one CPU to be operating in VMX mode(root or non-root) and another (or other) to be executing in legacy (non-VMX) mode?

Explanation in this regard will be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

> *VMXON* — This instruction takes a single 64-bit source operand that is in memory. It causes a **logical processor**
>   to enter VMX root operation and to use the memory referenced by the operand to support VMX operation.

<sup>Emphasis mine</sup>

You can find the answer to this type of questions directly in the [Intel Manuals, Volume 3, Chapters 23-33](https://www-ssl.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-system-programming-manual-325384.pdf)

The quote state that the effect of enabling VMX is limited to the *logical processor* that is executing the suitable instruction.
Each CPU has its set of cores and each core has its set of logical processors, thus each "CPU" has seen by the end user operates independently.